# Send emails using Strapi

Tags: strapi

I have not understood how the Strapi email plugin works.:(

If I only use Strapi-Sendmail, how do I send a mail from Localhost over port 25 so that I can test locally if my Strapi sends mail?

Why does the recipient("to") have to be "admin@strapi.io"? I can enter any sender, if I use PHP.
A little introduction would be helpful!

Setting on "Public" just for test:
[image]

In "Email.js":

[image]

Tested via Postman:

[image]

I read this article, unfortunately I have not completely understood yet.
[Send mails](https://medium.com/@kainikhil/send-emails-using-strapi-%EF%B8%8F-24184071de21)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds that Strapi default sendmail provider doesn't work locally.
You should create an account on http://sendgrid.com, generate an API key and install npm library on your server : `npm i strapi-provider-email-sendgrid`

At last you choose sendgrid provider in Strapi, enter your API key and enjoy !

[image: strapi]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try it this week! :)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer and suggestion. Sendgrid works very well!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.  Take in count that SendGrid requires you to perform either a Domain Authentication or Single Sender Verification and when testing your implementation you have to use a sender from that same domain or equal to your configured Single Sender, other ways you will get a non-related code error.

Comment: Hi, I cannot find "Email - Settings" page in strapi admin. How can I navigate to it? I use strapi 3.0.1

Comment: Hi, @podeig after release 3.0.0 Strapi removed UI for Email - Settings. Now you can make all configuration into code. All you need to install package you want to use: mailgun, nodemailer ..., create file config/plugins.js and add configuration you want. Below I'm adding sample configuration: https://pastebin.com/M1NMH7nG

Answer (score 2):

Yes it worked for me. Create an account on Sendgrid and enter your secret ID it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's time to continue my Strapi project. :) I will test with Sendgrid and report the result as soon as possible. Best regards!

Comment: @vinzcelavi  I am trying to follow the steps you mentioned here. I am getting 401 error when trying to use forgot password api. Can you please tell me what will be my to and from field. I already have key.